Print the first text - delete it and then print the second text
I had previously created a question similar to this:
Display the second text after finishing printing the first text
But now I want to print a text, then delete it word by word at the same speed as I printed the text, and then type the second text at the same speed.
For this purpose, I wrote the following code:


const text1 = "Your first sentence here"; // Enter your first sentence here
const text2 = "Your second sentence here"; // Enter your second sentence here

let i = 0;

function typeSentence(text, element) {
  const interval = setInterval(() => {
    if (i === text.length) {
      clearInterval(interval);
      if (text === text1) {
        clearText();
      }
    } else {
      element.text(element.text() + text[i]);
      i++;
    }
  }, 100); // Speed of animation (adjust as needed)
}

function clearText() {
  const interval = setInterval(() => {
    if (!$("#loading-text").text()) {
      clearInterval(interval);
      typeSentence(text2); // Call typeSentence to print the second sentence
    } else {
      $("#loading-text").text($("#loading-text").text().substring(0, $("#loading-text").text().length - 1));
    }
  }, 100); // Speed of animation (adjust as needed)
}

typeSentence(text1, $('#loading-text'));
 #loading-text {
            font-size: 24px;
            font-weight: bold;
            text-align: center;
            margin: 20px auto;
            width: 50%;
            opacity: 1;
        }
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="loading-text"></div>



The above code correctly types and deletes the first text, but does not type the second text!
According to the answer that was created for my previous question, I edited the code as follows:


const text1 = "Your first sentence here"; // Enter your first sentence here
const text2 = "Your second sentence here"; // Enter your second sentence here

const texts = [text1, text2]; // Array of sentences
const element = $('#loading-text'); // Element to display text

let i = 0;
let currentTextIndex = 0; // Index of the current sentence in the array

function typeSentence() {
  if (i < texts[currentTextIndex].length) {
    element.text(element.text() + texts[currentTextIndex][i]);
    i++;
  } else {
    if (currentTextIndex < texts.length - 1) {
      // Clear the element and move to the next sentence
      clearText();
    } else {
      clearInterval(tId); // Stop typing if all sentences are finished
    }
  }
}

function clearText() {
  i = 0; // Reset character index
  currentTextIndex++; // Move to the next sentence in the array
  element.text(""); // Clear the element content
}

// Start typing the first sentence
const tId = setInterval(typeSentence, 100); // Speed of animation (adjust as needed)
 #loading-text, #loading-text2 {
            font-size: 24px;
            font-weight: bold;
            text-align: center;
            margin: 20px auto;
            width: 50%;
            opacity: 1;
        }
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="loading-text"></div>



This code correctly prints the second text, but creates a new problem!
After printing the first text, it should be deleted at the previous speed, and then the second text is printed, but this does not happen, and after the first text is printed, it immediately disappears and the second text starts to be printed!

Did you see the console errors when it tries to print the second text?

You're missing the element argument to typeSentence() when you call it from clearText(). You should pass element as an argument.
You also need to reset i back to 0 before calling typeSentence() again.


const text1 = "Your first sentence here"; // Enter your first sentence here
const text2 = "Your second sentence here"; // Enter your second sentence here

let i = 0;

function typeSentence(text, element) {
  const interval = setInterval(() => {
    if (i === text.length) {
      clearInterval(interval);
      if (text === text1) {
        clearText(element);
      }
    } else {
      element.text(element.text() + text[i]);
      i++;
    }
  }, 100); // Speed of animation (adjust as needed)
}

function clearText(element) {
  const interval = setInterval(() => {
    if (!element.text()) {
      clearInterval(interval);
      i = 0;
      typeSentence(text2, element); // Call typeSentence to print the second sentence
    } else {
      element.text(element.text().substring(0, $("#loading-text").text().length - 1));
    }
  }, 100); // Speed of animation (adjust as needed)
}

typeSentence(text1, $('#loading-text'));
#loading-text {
            font-size: 24px;
            font-weight: bold;
            text-align: center;
            margin: 20px auto;
            width: 50%;
            opacity: 1;
        }
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="loading-text"></div>



